# Why didn't Putin attend the BRICS summit in person?

Tags: russian-federation, international-criminal-court, south-africa

Why didn't Putin attend the BRICS summit in person? I understand that the International Criminal Court [issued an arrest warrant against him](https://apnews.com/article/icc-putin-war-crimes-ukraine-9857eb68d827340394960eccf0589253), but isn't it insulting to Putin and the South African government that a foreign court was able to prevent him from attending the summit? Wouldn't ignoring this warrant reinforce BRICS' aims of creating a multi-polar world?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Going to BRICS summit in person would be an excercise of "gambling with cheaters" that makes sense to avoid. Though, the government of Russia usually seems to be quite late into that revelation. After all, it took them a year of "grain deal" where Ukraine got to bombard Russian ports with drones, and Russia got nothing.

Best case scenario: You go to South Africa and show how you are all for new multi-polar world.

Worse case: You try to go to South Africa and either are not let in or some coutries between Russia and South Africa refuse to grant flyover rights, and you are humiliated.

Worst case: You go to South Africa, get kidnapped there or somewhere in the middle, with possible implications of hot World War III, Russian state collapse, or nuclear war.

Comment: make sense, thank you

Comment: One day you will realize, that russian fuhrer is the biggest cheater. But in comparison to original fuhrer, this one is scared of everything.

Comment: Not entirely sure what Bayraktar has to do with this as Turkey is not [officially] in BRICS. I guess your point is that China and India are just as unreliable "friends" for Russia. While I was googling for the famous remark that I could somewhat recall, it turns out it [was](https://tass.com/russia/789866) about allies. Putin still [says](https://tass.com/politics/1528795) Russia has many friends (unlike allies).

Comment: I'm not sure what BRICS has to do this. South Africa is in Commonwealth, isn't it? And Putin on complicated terms with London? That alone would make it a no go.

Comment: @alamar Perhaps understandably, coming from a Russian background -"near abroad" and all that, you seem to think Commonwealth membership gives the UK some say in how South Africa runs its domestic and international policy.  It doesn't.  And the BRICS angle is the BRICS summit, in South Africa (hint:  also in question title).

Comment: This is funny in the context that BRICS was basically a product of British think tanks.

Answer (score 7):

Since South Africa has voluntarily chosen to be under the jurisdiction of the International Criminal Court by signing the Rome Statute, it is no insult for it to be expected to abide by the rulings of that court.

Comment: Although I wonder what the precedents are.  Has any signatory country in the past conveniently "forgotten" an ICC warrant on a known visit/residence  (i.e. not something like Pakistan "not knowing" about Bin Laden - which wasn't ICC)?

Answer (score 0):

> Why didn't Putin attend the BRICS summit in person? I understand that the International Criminal Court issued an arrest warrant against him, but isn't it insulting to Putin and the South African government that a foreign court was able to prevent him from attending the summit? Wouldn't ignoring this warrant reinforce BRICS' aims of creating a multi-polar world?

The ICC has issued an arrest warrant for President Putin, accusing him of the war crime of deporting Ukrainian children to Russia. South Africa, as an ICC member, was obliged to arrest him should he turn up for the summit.  When South Africa's President couldn't guarantee they wouldn't arrest Putin he chose not to attend.  The ICC has 123 members with that obligation of arresting Putin should he travel.  President Putin can still travel to China and I think one country in Africa with no lay overs.

Is it insulting for Putin to be charged with kidnapping children?  One would expect.